# Can this type of constraint be recasted to a convex constraint?

Tags: convex-optimization

I have an optimization problem where all the constraints are linear but some of the type:
$$
y_i = \frac{x_i}{\sum_k x_k}
$$

It seems that the equality can be relaxed to an inequality adding the linear constraint:
$$
\sum_k y_k =1.
$$

I further have the constraints:
$$x_i\geq0$$
$$0\leq y_i \leq 1$$

The question is if the relaxed inequality is (or can be recasted as) a convex constraint?
$$
y_i \leq \frac{x_i}{\sum_k x_k}
$$

If I analyze it as a quadratic constraint $$\mathbf{x}^T A \mathbf{x} - b \mathbf{y} \leq 0,$$ the corresponding matrix $A$ has all zeros in the main diagonal (since there are no squared variables) and shows a negative eigenvalue, so the matrix is not positive semidefinite, and thus, the constraint is not convex.

I have also looked into the possibility of recasting the constraint as a Geometric Programming one:
$$
y_i\, x_i^{-1} \,\sum_k x_k  \leq 1
$$
 but then I face that I don't know if a geometric programming problem can mix constraints in the transformed variables and the original ones.

Any hint towards where to look would be very appreciated!